# Complex numbers resolving cos and sin

Tags: complex-numbers

I've got a problem with finding main argument of these complex number. How can i evaluate this two examples?

$$\sin \theta - i\cos \theta$$

$$\frac{(1-i\tan \theta)}{1+\tan \theta}$$

Comment: main argument??

Comment: In my country it is called so, in other words the angle which is then placed in trigonometry form.

Comment: My guess is that this is a reference to the Arg(z) function

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for Arg(z)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\arg(zw)=\arg(z)+\arg(w)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\arg(\sin(\theta)-i\cos(\theta))
&=\arg(-i)+\arg(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))\\
&=\theta-\frac\pi2
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\arg\left(\frac{1-i\tan(\theta)}{1+\tan{\theta}}\right)
&=\arg(\cos(-\theta)+i\sin(-\theta))-\arg(\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta))\\
&=-\theta+\pi[\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)\lt0]
\end{align}
$$
where $[\dots]$ are [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). Note that $\arg(z)$ is determined mod $2\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so clear what you mean, perhaps it's meant (where $z$ is a complex variable, here $z:=r(\cos\phi +i\sin\phi)$ with $r\in\mathbb{R}$):

$\displaystyle \sin\phi-i\cos\phi=-i\frac{z}{|z|}$

$\displaystyle \frac{1-i\tan\phi}{1+\tan\phi}=\frac{2\overline{z}}{(1-i)z+(1+i)\overline{z}}$